# Why does Kipling use an apostrophe on 'rickshaw?

Tags: apostrophe, contractions, japanese

Kipling's short story [The Phantom 'Rickshaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Phantom_%27Rickshaw_and_Other_Tales) has, as we can see, a leading apostrophe on the word "rickshaw".  Why does it have one?  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulled_rickshaw), "rickshaw" is directly from the Japanese (*rikisha*, 力車), without any obvious contraction involved.  Is there a contraction that Wikipedia has missed, or is Kipling using the apostrophe for another function?

Comment: Be honest, did you read the entire Wikipedia article, specifically *The original name is "Jinrikisha", meaning "man-power-vehicle" in Japanese*?

Comment: @StuartF I've just checked, and that etymology has been prominent in the article for more than a year. It also appears in Wiktionary, which specifically mentions 'rickshaw and has a brief article on it. I'd vote to close, if this wasn't such a good example of a question which neglects any form of basic research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*’rickshaw* is a shortening of *jinrickshaw*, which is a [variant spelling of  *jinrikisha*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Jinrickshaw).

<sub>*jinrickshaw* attested:</sub>
<sub>[Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22jinrickshaw%22&tbm=bks)</sub>
<sub>[Google Images](https://www.google.com/search?&q=%22jinrickshaw%22&tbm=isch)</sub>

Comment: Thanks.  I've accepted this answer rather than Stuart F's as it clarifies that the uncontracted, Anglicized form is attested.

Answer (score 17):

According to the OED, Rickshaw is from the Japanese *jinrikisha*

> A light two-wheeled hooded vehicle having springs and two shafts, drawn by one or more men. First used in Japan c1870, but now common in other parts of the world

*jinrikisha* is attested in English from 1874. In Japanese it was sometimes shortened to *rikisha*, and this form later became popular in English as *rickshaw*, with the first citation in the OED from 1879.

Since *The Phantom 'Rickshaw* was first published in English in 1888, the longer form would be well known, and perhaps more common. Kipling probably used the shorter to appear more colloquial or knowledgeable of street slang.

- *Oxford English Dictionary*, s.v. “rickshaw (n.),” December 2023, https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/6979145878.
- *Oxford English Dictionary*, s.v. “jinrikisha (n.),” July 2023, https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/3006122953.

Comment: But there was never any *jinrickshaw* to shorten — so it’s still odd.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Apparently there was: OED -- **Rickshaw**: Formed within English, by clipping or shortening. **Etymon**: jinrikisha n. -- OED **Jinrikisha**: A light two-wheeled hooded vehicle having springs and two shafts, drawn by one or more men. First used in Japan c1870, but now common in other parts of the world; colloquially shortened to rickshaw. *1874 The jinrikisha only came into existence a year or two ago.* Lady Herbert, translation of J. A. von Hübner, Ramble round World vol. I. 406 / *1895 These jinrikishas are not really Japanese at all.* C. Roper, Zigzag Trav. vol. II. 169

Comment: @Greybeard — I think you missed my point: that there was no *jinrickshaw*, only a *jinrikisha* to shorten. But I have since found that [*jinrickshaw* is indeed a variant spelling of *jinrikisha*](https://www.google.com/search?&q=%22jinrickshaw%22&tbm=isch) — and *that* is the word that can be shortened to *’rickshaw* with the apostrophe.

Comment: Hmm... as "[jin]rikisha" was no more than a transliteration, its spelling did not settle down for a while and more or less anything that sounded right was accepted.

Comment: One might speculate that transliteration from the Japanese had fewer conventions back then; and if so, you could postulate "jinrickshaw" even if it was never attested.